# Configuring a property with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class similar to the following:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ChildType ChildType { get; set; }
    public IChildData? Data { get; set; }
}
```

`ChildType` is an enum. There are implementations of `IChildData` for some, but not all, values.

**The tables**

```
MainTable
=========
Id int,
ChildType int,
[..Some more columns..]

SomeChild
=========
Id int,
ParentId int
[..Some more columns..]
```

ParentId points on the main table and StepType in the main table are used to tell which child table to load the subclass from.

I'm struggling with the mapping configuration.

I thought that I should use discriminators, but I can't figure how how to tell that the discriminator is for the property and not for `MainClass`.

This won't work:

```
var config = modelBuilder.Entity<MainClass>();
config.HasDiscriminator(x => x.ChildType).HasValue<SomeChild>(ChildType.SomeValue);
```

It complains that the `SomeChild` class does not inherit `MainClass`. How can I make EF understand that it's for the child's property?

Comment: Should not it be something like `var config = modelBuilder.Entity<SomeBaseImplementorOfIChildData>();`?

Comment: Also what is the desired table structure? `MainClass` has fk into `IChildData` data table?

Comment: But the ChildType property is in the "MainClass" and not the child?

Comment: MainTable has a ChildType column and SomeChild table has a FK to the MainTable.

Comment: So the relation is one-to-many (one MainClass to many children datas)?

Comment: No. Each MainTable row has zero or one child, where the MainTable.ChildType decides which child table to load from.

Comment: If you have a table per child type then you will need a separate property for each such table. AFAIK SQL databases can't have one column to be a foreign key for multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

> No. Each MainTable row has zero or one child, where the MainTable.ChildType decides which child table to load from

Based on this comment you want to have a TPC/TPT inheritance for the child type with something like polymorphic foreign key in the main table, which is AFAIK is not natively supported by at least some SQL databases, which make it doubtful for support in the EF Core.

I would suggest to rethink your database design. Based on the provided info [table-per-hierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-hierarchy-and-discriminator-configuration) looks like an appropriate solution:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ChildDataBase? Data { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDataBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ChildType ChildType { get; set; }
    public MainClass Main { get; set; }
}
```

Note that 1) EF Core AFAIK does not work well with interfaces for entities so better to introduce a base class from the get-go 2) discriminator is required only for TPH and it is a property of the table containing the hierarchy [other inheritance patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-concrete-type-configuration) do not need it and operate based on the entity to table mapping.

If you still want to use TPC or TPT then you will need either to rely on EF Core generating join queries (as mentioned before - discriminator is not used) or write the query logic yourself (potentially without setting up the relations and removing or marking corresponding properties as not mapped).

Read [Foreign key constraints for TPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#foreign-key-constraints) part of the doc it also can shed some light on the internal workings of the EF Core in this regard.

Comment: But I can't have the ChildType in each child table or the child class. It would then have to be repeated in every table.

Comment: @jgauffin you will not. The only inheritance model with discriminator is TPH (table per hierarchy, which is recommended default approach for EF Core to handle inheritance) when there is only one table.

Comment: There are multiple child tables (10), but only once is referenced per main table row

Comment: @jgauffin then you want table per concrete type approach (TPC) added in .NET 7. EF does not use discriminators for it. See the linked docs.